# movies in slideshow continue to play behind current slide

Tags: jquery, vimeo, movies

I created a slideshow of movies from vimeo:

http://www.180dev.com/background2

When I skip from 1 movie to another, I can still hear the original movie. How do I get the current movie to stop?

I built the slideshow based on this: http://slidesjs.com/examples/linking/

Comment: Have you heard of the [froogaloop libraries](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript)? Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590340/jquery-pause-vimeo-universal-embed-when-hidden).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the vimeo API to make it stop. For example when you click to slide another video, you use the vimeo API to make the previous video to stop.

Comment: i've looked through the video settings/embed section and the only thing i see that might relate to this is 'outro' which deals with what happens after the video is finished. am i looking in the wrong area?

Comment: look here: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api and here are examples: http://player.vimeo.com/playground

Comment: wow, i'm in a bit over my heard now. i'll look into it and post my updated version. thanks for the help.

Comment: ok, i don't understand any of this but the 'BRAD' video in the first example is amazing.